# Transfer mouse movements to a GameObject in 3D according to camera position and rotation

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, camera, mouse

I'd like the game object to follow the mouse but I have trouble doing this when the object is in 3D and the camera has been rotated.

The only thing that seems to be true (and still it works only when camera isn't rotated) is :

- The visible X for the camera is equal to `2 * Mathf.Abs(object.position.z - camera.position.z)`
- The visible Y for the camera is equal to `VisibleX * (camera.pixelHeight / (float)camera.pixelWidth)` (casting to `float` to avoid `int` divided by `int` returning an `int`)

Comment: It looks like you're using Unity, is that right? Be sure to describe *how* you want the object to follow the mouse. Since we're in 3D, there's an infinite set of points along the ray from the camera through the mouse position, so we need some rule to choose which one to use. Often we'll snap the object to a particular depth from the camera, or snap it onto a particular plane or mesh in your scene, depending on what you want to do in your game.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry i'll add that i use Unity, what i want is to have the object following the mouse on the screen. @DMGregory

Comment: Yes, but as I said for any position of the mouse on screen, there are infinite points in 3D space that would position the object at the mouse position on screen — just closer or further away in depth. To know which one of these to use, we need some second rule like "the object should follow the mouse AND stay at a depth of 10 units in front of the camera" or "the object should follow the mouse AND stay on my ground plane" etc.

Comment: well for example if the camera is looking at the object with a 45 degrees angle from above, when you move the mouse up half of the mouse movement on y axis will be given to the object's y axis and the other half to the z axis, if that's clear

Comment: So you want to keep the object in a plane of constant depth in front of the camera, it sounds like.

Comment: yes i assume, my english is probably not good enough to express my needs i assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an object to snap to the mouse position while keeping the same depth in front of the camera, you can use the [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) convenience method:

```
// Capture the position of the mouse on screen/window,
// measured in pixels from the bottom-left corner.
Vector3 screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;

// Track the current depth of the object in front of the camera.
// (You could also set this to some fixed constant or stored variable)
screenPosition.z = Vector3.Dot(
                     object.transform.position - camera.transform.position,
                     camera.transform.forward
                   );

// Transform this screen position to a world position, 
// using the camera's transformation & projection/viewport settings.
Vector3 worldPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);

// Snap the object to this position.
object.transform.position = worldPosition;
```