# Instantiated game objects go in random directions

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script that instantiates projectiles and it is supposed to shoot them in the direction of my mouse.

This is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestSpell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float projectileForce;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            GameObject spell = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 myPos = transform.position;
            Vector2 direction = (mousePos - myPos).normalized;
            spell.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * projectileForce;
        }
    }
}
```

The projectile game object is a circle prefab with a circle collider and a rigid body 2D. The RB has a mass of 0.001 which is the closest to 0 it can be, and both drags are 0, and gravity is 0, and it has no constraints.

projectileForce is set to 2.

Video of what is happening: https://streamable.com/l7rps5

---

I'm using Unity 2020.3.23f1

Comment: Are you using a perspective camera, per chance? It looks to me like you forgot to provide the depth at which you want to project the point from the screen into the world. At zero depth, that projected point will always be exactly at the camera position.

Comment: I am. Do you know what I should do to get it on a certain Z cord? And what one? Or should I just use an ortho one?

Comment: [I show how to calculate the depth you want in this previous answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/167418/39518). Be sure to search for similar Q&A when you encounter a problem, as this one has been [answered](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183700/39518) more than [once](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158815/39518).